# Gradle: Copying file to target directory fails when it contains a locked file

Tags: gradle, deployment, build.gradle

I have a simple task to copy the (spring-boot) fat-jar that my build creates to another folder from which I can start it later:

```
task deployLocal(type: Copy, dependsOn: [assemble]) {
    from 'build/libs/core-0.4.jar'
    into "C:/Dev/project"
}
```

The target directory contains a locked file (from a database). When that db is already running, the copy task failes due to gradle not being able to create a snapshot of that file.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'deployLocal' property 'destinationDir' during up-to-date check.
Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Dev\project\db\write.lock'.
```

As the error message states, this is done for the UP-TO-DATE check.
I've tried making my task skip that test by declaring it to never be UP-TO-DATE, without success:

```
task deployLocal(type: Copy, dependsOn: [assemble]) {
    from 'build/libs/core-0.4.jar'
    into "C:/Dev/project"
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

Can I force gradle to skip creation of snapshots?